# Save photo to camera roll and return url

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to save a base64 image to camera roll and return the url for the saved image. The code works in so far as I have succeeded in saving to camera roll but I am seeing an error and no URL is returned. The error is:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=-1 "(null)"
```

My code is:

```
- (void)saveImageDataToLibrary:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{

    __block CDVPluginResult* result = nil;

    NSData* imageData = [NSData dataFromBase64String:[command.arguments objectAtIndex:0]];

    UIImage* image = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData] autorelease];

    __block PHObjectPlaceholder *placeholderAsset = nil;

    [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{

        PHAssetChangeRequest *newAssetRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImage:image];

        placeholderAsset = newAssetRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset;

    } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if(success){
            NSLog(@"worked");
            PHAsset *asset = [self getAssetFromlocalIdentifier:placeholderAsset.localIdentifier];

            PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions *options = [[PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions alloc] init];
            options.networkAccessAllowed = YES; //download asset metadata from iCloud if needed

            [asset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:options
                completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput *contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info) {
                NSURL *assetURL = contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL;
                NSString* url = [assetURL absoluteString];
                NSLog(@"our result is: %@", url);

                result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:url];
                [self invokeCallback:command withResult:result];

            }];

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsString:error.description];
            [self invokeCallback:command withResult:result];
        }
    }];

}

- (void) invokeCallback:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command withResult:(CDVPluginResult *)result {
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:command.callbackId];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:
**PHContentEditingOutput**

That object has a property called: **renderedContentURL**

Use that to get the appropriate URL of your PHAsset.

So to get the URL, your code should look like this:

```
PHContentEditingOutput *contentEditingOutput = [[PHContentEditingOutput alloc] initWithContentEditingInput:YOUR_PHCONTENTEDITING_INPUT];

NSURL *myPHAssetURL = [contentEditingOutput renderedContentURL];
```